# Can using memory on lower frequencies cause any physical damage to it over the years?

Tags: laptop, memory

I have got a laptop with 8GB of 2667MHz SODIMM memory.
I was planning on adding additional RAM. I have two choices either get a 2667MHz RAM or get 3200MHz and use that at the 2667MHz frequency, which will future proof my purchase as I can reinstall it on my new laptop later as 3200MHz is pretty much the standard now.

So, if I was to do this would there be any physical problems with the RAM over the years being used at 2667MHz?

My Motherboard config

[image: Motherboard Config]

My RAM config

[image: RAM Config]

Comment: No, only trying to force a *higher* frequency than designed could cause damage, if it were even allowed.

Comment: @Prab-mat - You won't see any performance gains from running the memory at the higher frequency outside of a benchmark, and overclocking your memory, won't decrease it's lifespan if it's properly cooled.  If PCB is going to fail, it will fail, overclocking rarely has anything to do with a memory module failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consult your motherboard manual to see which RAM types
are acceptable.

If the 3200 MHz RAM is acceptable, there will be no problem.
Most motherboards will accept a mixture of faster and slower RAM
sticks, normally adjusting automatically all RAM to work at the
same speed, which is that of the slower RAM.

Acer itself does publish any technical information for the model
Aspire A715-75G, so the answer needs to come from third-party
sources.

The
[Crucial](https://www.crucial.com/)
website for computer upgrades is very dependable.
Its RAM upgrade page for the
[Aspire A715-75G](https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/acer/aspire-a715-75g)
lists both types of RAM:

[image]

Ensure that the RAM you bought is relatively similar to the above
specs. But in any case, the motherboard is sure to support
both DDR4-3200 and DDR4-2666.

I think that it's highly likely that mixing both kinds of RAM
will work at the lower speed. However, it's always best to
buy from a vendor that has a good warranty and return policies,
such as Crucial.
You may further ask the question from the Crucial Support team;
their level of support is very good.

Comment: Yes, it will work on the lower freq of 2667MHz. Your answer helped me a lot here, the thing I was concerned about was, that if I were to use 3200MHz on lower freq will it cause any problem to the RAM module itself, any physical damage over long periods of time (2-3 years).

Comment: No need to worry, RAM does not degrade when used at lower frequencies. Only overclocking above the rated frequencies is dangerous in the long-term.

Comment: Yeah... sure it was and thank you a lot for helping!